# not able to return file as empty in python

Tags: python

I have a scenario which i am trying to implement , where i need to check file is empty or not
But need to consider below case statements

**Case 1 :** if file as empty lines and no records then message should be shown as File is Empty

**Case 2 :** if file as Only Spaces and no records then message should be shown as File is Empty

**Case 3 :** if file as Only tabs and no records then message should be shown as File is Empty

I have tried my below code , but not satisfying

**My python code :**

```
  import os


def isEmp(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        if f.tell():
            f.seek(0)
        else:
            print('File is Empty')
```

***Any approach to cover all above Cases 1,2,3***

Comment: `if not f.read().strip(): print('File is empty')`

Comment: ```if not f.read.strip()```, a non empty string is truth value so an empty string is false. ```if not True``` which is ```if False```, the string is empty so ```print('Empty file')```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def isEmp(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        contents = f.read().strip()
        if contents:
            # use contents here
            print("Not empty")
        else: 
            print("Empty")
```

You need to use `.strip()` to remove all the spaces or tabs at the beginning and the end of the file.

Comment: You should check `if len(contents) > 0`. Using `strip()` will just return an empty string if the file is all spaces.

Comment: `if contents: ` will return `False` if the string is empty

Comment: @Harshal Parekh Thanks it seems the not_speshal  comment should be consider I believe

Comment: In the code provided, all the 3 cases will work just fine @codeholic24